# Need to print the path for the texts on sub-directories (unix)

Tags: grep

I need to print the path for the texts. Suppose I have below sentence:

*How are you?*

Now I want to know what is the directory/file or a path to this text.

Comment: You have `unix` in the subject and `linux` in the tag. Does that mean it has to run on a [Unix system](https://www.opengroup.org/openbrand/register/) with a linux kernel? That would be Inspur K-UX right?

Comment: Are you looking for files that contain that string?

Comment: yes Jeff @JeffSchaller. It is with unix Stephane

Answer (score 0):

One method, POSIX-compatible

```
find ~ -type f -exec grep -l "How are you\?" {} \;
```

`find` is th command used to find files, and here we're limiting the search to your home directory (`~`).  The `-type f` option restricts the search to files, not directories.  Then `-exec` gives a command for `find` to run on each of these files, replacing `{}` with the current filename.  The command must be terminated with `\;`.

The `grep` command used here searches the contents of the file it is given for the string "How are you?".  Note that you must escape the question mark, as otherwise `grep` treats it saying "The `u` is optional."  The `-l` option causes `grep` to print, instead of the matching lines, the name of the input file if any matches are found.

Comment: Why not just `grep -lR 'How are you\?' $HOME/`?

Comment: @DopeGhoti Because I never want to assume anything non-POSIX — though it seems `-l` is there.  Thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @DopeGhoti I tried same but thought it won't work for spaced characters. But now again verified it works. Only problem is the my text files doesn't contain strings I was looking..

Comment: @fox The `{}` should not need quoting.

Comment: @Kusalananda Oh, indeed.  Post-edit I looked at my command-line history and wondered why I had never quoted `{}` — turns out I sort of knew what I was doing after all!